# Disk unknown usage

Tags: disk-usage

I use `df -h` find 17G used. However I use `ncdu /` to find which directory holding disk usage, show me only 5.5G used. What's wrong with this?

`df -h` screenshot:

[image: "df -h" screenshot]

`ncdu /` screenshot:

[image: "ncdu /" screenshot]

[Edit 2016.09.05]

It is resolved. I should use 'sudo ncdu /', then I found the usage is match for `df -h` usage.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

In a terminal type:

```
 sudo du -BM -s /*
```

This will give a summary of disk usage in each directory and file in the root directory, in megabytes.

You need sudo because you want to read all the files.

There is also a man page for du.

Comment: It is resolved. Inspired by your command . I should use 'sudo ncdu /', then i found the usage is match to `df -h` usage. Thank you.